# Exception on retrieving an Integer field value using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, type-conversion

I am on JDK 1.8 and trying to retrieve the value of a field, which is marked as **Integer** and not **int**.

*I can't change Data Type to int because this class is used by Lucene and an OR/M, so I can only use Reflection to play with it*

```
private Integer fee;

public Integer getFee() {
    return fee;
}

public void setFee(Integer fee) {
    this.fee = fee;
}
```

When I do the following:

```
Field field = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("fee");
field.setAccessible(true);
Integer fee = field.getInt(myInstance);
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Attempt to get java.lang.Integer field "com.xyz.models.MyModel.fee" 
with illegal data type conversion to int
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

- It's not an int, so don't use `getInt`. Use `get` and cast it.
- You are passing a string "fee" where it is expecting some class instance

```
Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("fee");
field.setAccessible(true);
Integer fee = (Integer) field.get(someInstance);
```

Given that your class already has a getter, I don't see why you need to access this field via reflection. Just use `someInstance.getFee()`.

Comment: It was a typo in my Question, I fixed.
By using this:
```Integer val = (Integer)field.get(someInstance);```, it works.